# Send List of String to WebApi with ProtoBuff

Tags: asp.net-web-api, protobuf-net

I want to send a List(Of String) in protobuf format to a WebApi services.
I tried the solution below but the data object is Nothing.
How can i set the propertyname of the ByteArray or can i use the FormUrlEncodedContent?

What do i wrong?

I searched on the internet but i can't get a correct solution.
I hope that my question is clear.

```
Dim articleList As List(Of String)
articleList.Add("134545454") 
Using client As New HttpClient()
  client.BaseAddress = New Uri(WEB_URL)
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"))
  Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
  ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(Of List(Of String))(stream, articleList)
  stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
  Dim data As New ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray)
  data.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/x-protobuf")
  Dim response = client.PostAsync("MutatieLijst", data).Result
```

Webapi Call:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function GetArtikelMutatieLijst(ByVal data As List(Of String)) As List(Of ArtikelUpdate)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API is based upon Media Formatters to parse and format values. But Web APi only includes the following formatters: XML, JSON, BSON, and form-urlencoded.

If you want to send and receive data in a different format, which you do with `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers, you need to implement your own formatter.

Here you have two examples to implement media formmaters, but you can get more if you google for "Web APi custom media formatters":

- [Media Formatters in ASP.NET Web API 2. Sample of csv formatter.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)
- [Implementing Custom Media Formatters in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559378/Implementing-Custom-Media-Formatters-in-ASP-NET-We)

Basically, you need:

- to derive a class from `MediaTypeFormatter` or `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter` (for asynchronous or synchronousimplemetations)

  - include in the constructor the supported MIME types
  - implement `CanWriteType`, `CanreadType`, `WriteToStream` and `ReadFromStream`
- register the media formatter class in Web API configuration

Take into account that the formatter will be used:

- to parse the received data, when the media format is specified in `Content-Type` header
- to serialize the returned object when the media format is specified with `Accept` header

Comment: Thank you. With your information i have changed: data.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/x-protobuf") to data.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf") and now it works.